# How to define different file upload limits for different controllers?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I have 2 pages in my Phoenix app, and they need different limits for the size of the file uploads (one page is fine with the default 8MB limit, but the second one needs a higher limit).

From the docs, I can increase the limit in the MyApp.Endpoint module, like this:

```
plug Plug.Parsers,
  parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
  pass: ["*/*"],
  json_decoder: Poison,
  length: 15000000
```

but this settings is site-wide. I tried moving the whole Parsers plug directly to the controllers, but when submitting the form I get an error

```
no route found for POST ...
```

so I assume the parsers plug is needed before the router. I also tried moving only the :multipart parser to the controller, but that results in the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your actual issue with increasing the limit for the entire application?

Comment: I have user-uploaded content which I want to limit in size, and admin-uploaded content without a limit.

Comment: Why not setting a second endpoint for your admin up?